# Couldn't do inner join in grid view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, grid, inner-join

I'm totally new to asp.net. Please help

I'm trying to connect two tables using inner join. It worked when the query is: 
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;

But throws this error "A field or property with the name 'CustomerName' is not found on the selected data source" when the query is changed to:

SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;

But When I tested the query, it ran successfully

Note: I'm using access db with SQL data source and using vb for asp.net

Comment: What is the schema of the table Customers?

Answer (score 1):

It appears your Customers table doesn't contain column with the name 'CustomerName'. Can you check this real good please.. maybe a typo?

Open the database using access to check this.

Answer (score 0):

when using a grid view you have to make sure that your columns are correct in your bind

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbtitle" runat="server" Text='<%#     Bind("title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbltitle" runat="server" Text='<%#  Bind("title") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

above, title is my column name in my DB table.  Same when using DataKeyNames, your value must be equal to a column name.

Answer (score 0):

That was a very simple mistake from my side ., apologies! I missed to update the query in the code for search button, thanks people.